# Running phantomjs in Android environment

Tags: android, phantomjs, headless-browser

I have an architecture in place that is working OK... basically my Android app sends some options to a node.js server, those options are processed at the server and related data is fetched, and the fetched data is then processed at the server by running [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) to generate an output image that is sent back to my Android app (to be displayed in an `ImageView`).  The remote phantomjs is effectively used in place of a local browser (I'm restricted to displaying the output in an `ImageView` rather than using a `WebView` directly at the device).

However, since in some cases the generated image can be quite large, I'd quite like to be able to use a similar architecture (with the same code base), but just to do the image generation locally, at the device, rather than remotely.

So the architecture would be: send options from device to node.js server (as before), process and fetch related data at server (as before), send the fetched data to Android device (new) and run phantomjs at Android device to generate image (new).

So, the "only" difference really is that I'm running phantomjs at the device rather than at the server.

Is there any possible way to get phantomjs running on Android?

Comment: *Probably* with a lot of headache. Prepare to bang your head on the desk multiple times an hour.

Comment: Well I banged my head already multiple times just to get phantomjs running at the server, so I'm used to it... am willing to consider some other (non-phantomjs) headless browser for generating an output image from html+js (where the html has just a single container, and where the clever stuff is done in the js to populate the html container).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpUnit/HtmlUnit equivalent for android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721544/httpunit-htmlunit-equivalent-for-android)