# Download files from web page

Tags: java, networking

I want to download pdf files from http://bookzz.org/ using java. How I can pass a file name to the site and get list to choose from? How can I make all these steps run in the background?

Comment: Please show us your attempt and the code and we can review it to see what could be changed. The site is not a code writing service or tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use e.g. [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) to access a web site via java. 
You can use this to perform searches in the form and than use the links to download the files.

Comment: Thank you 
But is their any way to do this using java code only because i want to make this project in android also ,

Comment: Its seams that there is a *selenium* driver for android http://stackoverflow.com/a/9722656/1921273