# Headless browser

Tags: java, android, web-scraping, headless-browser

I need an headless browser for android, like `PhantomJS`, but it seems that there is nothing like that. I only need it to do some web scraping, but the content of the page is loaded with javascript, so I can't use `Jsoup` for example. I've seen some solutions that suggested to use a webview without any layout to do so, but it's very tricky and I want to avoid using a context. Also I need it to be synchronous, so I can use it with RxJava. Is there any working solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721544/httpunit-htmlunit-equivalent-for-android

Comment: This isn't a real solution, as it require to install a separate app.